# How to modal in PHP with delete confirmation

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to add a modal in my system that when you click it a modal will appear and ask you a confirmation if you want to delete that certain data.

But in my present code, when you click the button, it will direct you to a blank page without modal. The `id` is passing correctly but how can I output the modal?

Here's my code for PHP:

```
        <?php

        while(mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt)) {
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td class=\"col-md-2\" onclick=\"document.location = 'modal_delete.php?id=$id';\"><button type=\"button\" class=\"btn btn-primary btn-md\" data-toggle=\"modal\" data-target=\"#myModal\">Delete</button></td>";
        echo '</tr>';
      }

      ?>
```

Here is the code for the modal (modal_delete.php):

```
<?php

include '../session.php';
include 'header.php';

?>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        ...
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Delete</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I hope guys you help me. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On `modal_delete.php` you need to trigger the modal using javascript after the DOM is ready.

```
<script>
  $(function () {
   $('#myModal').modal('show');
 });
</script>
```

Comment: i will just add this codes in my `modal_delete.php?`

Comment: I would suggest reading up on what php, html and javascript do and how the pieces fit together.  Doing something without understanding is not really helpful.

Comment: im actually reading javascript these past days. i have a good knowledge in php and html. thanks